# Is it possible to enable query + index service on an existing 1-node cluster?

Tags: couchbase, sql++

Can you enable query + index service on an existing 1 node cluster?

When we fire query in Couchbase 6.0.0 Select Query WorkBench, then 
an error occurs:

> No index available on keyspace demo that matches your query. Use CREATE INDEX or CREATE PRIMARY INDEX to create an index, or check that your expected index is online.

So we have to enabled query and index service. Is this possible in an existing cluster?

Comment: Why did you tag a question about Couchbase with `couchdb`?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, this cannot be done once you've already set up a node. If you've already set up your cluster and did not select index/query services, then you will have to setup again (or add another node with index/query services). You aren't the first to ask, and you can learn more about this feature request here: [MB-15357](https://issues.couchbase.com/browse/MB-15357)

**The error message you're seeing, however** suggests that you DO have index/query services setup. The error message simply means you haven't actually created an index. You could start by creating a primary index:

`CREATE PRIMARY INDEX ON mybucketname`

This is not recommended for production, but then again neither is a 1-node cluster. To learn more about creating indexes, you can check out the [Couchbase documentation on Indexes and query performance](https://docs.couchbase.com/server/current/learn/services-and-indexes/indexes/indexing-and-query-perf.html).